Why does the server suddenly send a RST after 3-way handshake?
The local computer attempts to connect to a remote server via SSH, but after the three-way handshake is accepted, the remote server suddenly sends a RST. If the local computer switches to a different network, it can successfully remote connect. I’m unsure which SSH configuration could cause this.
I checked the firewall on the remote server, and it doesn’t seem to be blocking certain IPs from accessing port 22. Moreover, even if it were blocking, the three-way handshake shouldn’t succeed.I don’t think it’s a firewall issue.

Probably the SSH server isn't configured to allow connections from your IP address, so it resets the connection, which already got accepted before SSHD got control.

One can only speculate without further information. But if the RST depends on the source network than the problem might either the target blocking the source or some blocking in the source network itself, i.e. some DPI firewall in your local network blocking access. If you have access to the target server than check if the RST actually originates from the server or is injected in your local network. If it is generated by the server check the server logs.

wow!!!you are so clever!!! Thank you very much!!!

Inspired by Steffen Ullrich’s comment, I realized that the issue might not be caused by the server, meaning that the server was not blocking any IP address connections. It could only be a problem with the source IP. Therefore, I used tcpdump to check and found that my computer’s public IP router had an issue. After connecting to the remote server, it sent a RST to the server. Here is the content of the packet capture:

15:11:57.716556 IP 36.112.35.237.clutild > 10.206.0.4.ssh: Flags [S],
seq 3484290503, win 64240, options [mss 1344,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0


15:11:57.716626 IP 10.206.0.4.ssh >
36.112.35.237.clutild: Flags [S.], seq 1720587517, ack 3484290504, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0


15:11:57.753501 IP 36.112.35.237.clutild > 10.206.0.4.ssh: Flags [R.],
seq 1, ack 1, win 21845, length 0

However, I still don’t know what caused 36.112.35.237 to send a RST to my server.
